# Algorithm to compute maximum independent set of graph with maximum block size k with comlexity $O(f(k)\cdot p(|V(G)|)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, graph-connectivity

### Definitions

Definition block: Let $G$ be a undirected Graph. A maximal 2-connected subgraph (subgraph without biconnected component) of $G$ is called a block.
[image]

Definition maximum independent set: An independent set is a set of vertices in a graph, no two of which are adjacent. A maximum independent set is an independent set of largest possible size for a given graph $G$.

### Question

Let $G$ be a undirected, connected Graph. All blocks $B\subseteq G$ satisfy $|V(B)| \leq k$.
Let $f(k)$ be a be any function, and $p(|V(G)|)$ any polynomial. The task is, to find an Algorithm, that finds a maximum independent set of $G$ with $O(f(k)\cdot p(|V(G)|)$ complexity.

---

So far i know how to compute all blocks in $O(|V(G)|^2\cdot |E(G)|)$ and maximum independent sets via brute force in $O(2^{|V(G)|}\cdot |V(G)|^2)$. My guess is, that i have to brute force independent sets of every block in the graph and then somehow merge the the right solutions/i-sets to one set. I struggle with the latter. Thanks in andvance for any answers/hints.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you say a few words about the origin of the question? (I know an expert, and I can ask his help provided you need a solution for your research or job, but I cannot ask him about a solution of a homework or an exam problem).

Comment: This is one of the problems my professor gave me to study for the upcoming exam.

Comment: I would really appreciate a hint of some sort, so that i can still solve the problem myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. As a hint to anyone who wants to find an algorithm: you have to calculate the [block-graph (this is a german link, the english wiki for block-graph is something else)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockgraph) and then use the fact, that a block-graph always is a tree.